# Laravel file upload just send file name to controller

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

I am trying to upload an image.

Here is my html form:

```html
<form class="form" action="{{ URL::to('/alunos/cadastrar') }}" method="post" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
    <label for="nome"  >Nome</label>
    <input  type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome"><br><br>

    <label for="serie"  >Série</label>
    <input  type="text" name="serie" placeholder="serie"><br><br>

    <label for="escola"  >Escola</label>
    <input  type="text" name=escola placeholder="escola"><br><br>

    <label for="turno"  >Turno</label>
    <input  type="text" name=turno placeholder="Turno"><br><br>

    <label for="documento"  >Documento</label>
    <input  type="text" name=documento placeholder="documento"><br><br>

    <label for="residencia"  >Reside em</label>
    <input  type="text" name=residencia placeholder="Reside em"><br><br>

    <label for="rota"  >Rota</label>
    <input  type="text" name=rota placeholder="rota"><br><br>

    <label for="data_nasc"  >Data de Nascimento</label>
    <input  type="text" name=data_nasc placeholder="Data de Nascimnento"><br><br>

    <label for="mae"  >Mãe</label>
    <input  type="text" name=mae placeholder="Mãe"><br><br>

    <label for="pai"  >Pai</label>
    <input  type="text" name=pai placeholder="Pai"><br><br>

    <label for="photo"  >Foto</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Registrar!">
</form>
```

And here is the controller method:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Every time it runs, get the error message. And dd(request()->all()) gives the following.

```
array:12 [▼
  "nome" => null
  "serie" => null
  "escola" => null
  "turno" => null
  "documento" => null
  "residencia" => null
  "rota" => null
  "data_nasc" => null
  "mae" => null
  "pai" => null
  "photo" => "23722217_17536056.jpg"
  "_token" => "TPYBg3d8f3CdiQQnMbimprb5HQPkxqG5MSLdAUEa"
]
```

The 'photo' field doesn't actually have the file, just the file name.

I am working in a MacBook Pro with MAMP. In the top of controller code, I have the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Quotation;
use Datatables;
use App\aluno;
use View;
use PDF;
use DB;
```

How could I make this upload work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems correct.

The only thing that MIGHT be the issue is your enctype has different types of quotes.

Try changing:

```
enctype=”multipart/form-data”
```

To

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```